# Change color of seaborn distribution line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, seaborn

I want to specify the color of a line of `fit` within the seaborn package for an array of `x` and `y` data. Instead all I can figure out is how to change the color and shading for the kernel density function. How can I change the color for a gaussian fit? I.e. the lines below should be red and blue. It would also be great to shade in the function like the `"shade":True` argument.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(x,kde_kws={"shade":True}, kde=False, fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, color="red", label="label 1");
sns.distplot(y,kde_kws={"shade":True}, kde=False, fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, color="blue", label="label 2");
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For changing the color of the fitted curve, you need to set `fit_kws` argument. But `fit_kws` does not support shading. You can still shade the area below the fitted curve by a few extra lines of code as shown below but that I think is an answer to another question that you have posted.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.normal(loc=6.0, scale=1, size=(50,))

ax = sns.distplot(x, fit_kws={"color":"red"}, kde=False,
        fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, label="label 1");
ax = sns.distplot(y, fit_kws={"color":"blue"}, kde=False,
        fit=stats.gamma, hist=None, label="label 2");

plt.show(block=False)
```

The result of the code is show below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a tough time finding the arguments for `fit_kws`. Bummer that's it's complicated to shade.

Comment: Yes. It is a bit complicated to shade.